# ¿ Cómo elegir el tipo de dato para una columna en una tabla de SQL Server cuando el valor siempre será dos valores?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo dudas cuando tengo que guardar en base de datos una nueva columna de una tabla donde los valores son siempre 2 opciones.

Ejemplo: Carga y Descarga

En SQL Server es mejor hacer
[Operacion] NVARCHAR(10)  Guardando "Carga" y "Descarga"

o

[Operacion] BIT Guardando para Carga un 0 y Descarga un 1

o

[Carga] BIT Guardando 1 para Carga y 0 sería que es Descarga

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: No debe haber duda, la segunda opción es la buena, por espacio ocupado, por eficiencia y por las reglas de normalización.

Comment: Me parece la más correcta. Pero siempre me queda la duda de que si se hace una consulta a la tabla si el desarrollador no sabe que 0 es Carga  de un simple vistazo no va a saber de que va esa columna...

Comment: Si la columna se llama Carga, no debe quedat duda. También puedes poner un tinyint y poner una tabla relacionada con el texto Carga/Descarga

Comment: Genial, gracias.